# Guess application of passworded OOXML document?

Tags: java, c#, c++, ms-office, openxml

does anyone know how to guess a type of OOXML office document (Excel, Word, PP, etc.) by its structure if the document is *password-protected*?

I found a way to guess the application of unprotected OOXML document, but now I need to recognize the type of protected one.

Will be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: ... by its extension?...

Comment: As Simon said - by it's file extension. Otherwise encrypted files use the Microsoft Compound File Binary (CFB) format - which can incorporate entire directory structures. Look here for the [CFB specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/[MS-CFB].pdf). Also see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/07/17/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents.aspx).

Comment: Thank you both for replies! 
It's a pity, but in this case extension can be a misleading way to determine the actual office application. 
I took a look at CFB specification, as @PaulF suggested, but there are no specific directory entries in protected document, from which one can determine which app created the document. Also, I examined the second [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/07/17/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents.aspx) by PaulF. There they tell about CFB header, and provide no info on determining actual office app..

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions, guys?

I'm looking for more reliable way, similar to the one, where 97-2003 binary format files are [recognized](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/01/16/determining-office-binary-file-format-types.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the way to guess application of passworded OOXML document if it doesn't have an extension (if it comes in stream).

What is more, if one renames, for example, a passworded *.docx file into *.pptx , a PowerPoint will run with an "Enter password" dialog box appeared without any exception. An exception will appear only if you enter correct password, but until that it seems that EITHER there is a way to guess appliation of passworded document but office doesn't do that check OR there is no way to guess (until the password is entered).